# ddwrt:FormatDate is reverting date parts

Tags: xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I'm using a custom XSLT file to format the oob created column to not show time, only date.

I have this code :

```
  <xsl:template name="FieldRef_ValueOf.Created"
                match="FieldRef[@Name='Created']"
                mode="DateTime_body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode"
               select="." />
    <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate($thisNode/@Created,1036,1)" />
  </xsl:template>
```

As you can see, I specify the 1036 (French) culture.

However, this produces the date in the wrong format : *month/day/year* (`01/10/2012`), instead of the expected *day/month/year* (`10/01/2012`).

Why does this method behaves like this? How can I correct this?

FYI, if I set up the 1033 culture, the date is now in the correct *French* format.

In fact, the day and month seems to be swapped.

**[edit]** I found a [KB entry at Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580994). The XsltListViewWebPart seems to buggy. Unfortunately, the suggested workaround are not very satisfying.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested, but this might work:

```
ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string($thisNode/@Created), 1036, 'ddMMyyyy')
```

**Edit**

This worked for me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template name="FieldRef_DateTime_body.Created" match="FieldRef[@Name='Created']"  mode="DateTime_body" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body">
        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string($thisNode/@Created), 1036, 'dd/MM/yyyy')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws a `System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
`

Comment: this will works if your SPWeb's locale is 1033. But if the site is not english (mine is 1036, French), the formatdate and the xsltlistviewwebpart won't use the same locale (one of them is 1033, the other is 1036). That will cause a double swap of my dates' component. Take a look in the KB for explanation.

Comment: Strange, my site is 1044 (norwegian)

Comment: maybe the behavior is different from one locale to another, depending on the order of components.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$thisNode/@Created` is represented in french format (10/02/2013 for Feb 10th, 2013), but the `FormatDateTime()` function expects it to be the other way round (i.e. understands October 2nd).
This is in particular annoying, because it tries to tolerate "obvious errors" like 31/12/2013, which becomes correctly Dec 31st (which ShPt beleives is 12/31/2013) on any system.

Thus,

```
FormatDateTime('10/02/2013', nls, 'dd+MM') = '02+10'
FormatDateTime('31/12/2013', nls, 'dd+MM') = '31+12'
```

whatever nls is (1033 or 1036 or ...), but only on french (or german, or slovene, ...) systems. However it does not give these contradictory results on US-installed ShPt servers (with SPWeb's locale 1033).

Got it?